# Cannot setup TPU in Colab using any methods with Jax

Tags: google-colaboratory, tpu, jax

I have searched high and low and tried to set up TPU with flax. [This notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rwbfd/cc43641645ee7fd3463d8dcbff7fbb97/geekbang_chapter_13_part3.ipynb) is my closest attempt. The error message is very strange.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jax/tools/colab_tpu.py in setup_tpu(tpu_driver_version)
     36 
     37   if not TPU_DRIVER_MODE:
---> 38     colab_tpu_addr = os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'].split(':')[0]
     39     url = f'http://{colab_tpu_addr}:8475/requestversion/{tpu_driver_version}'
     40     requests.post(url)

/usr/lib/python3.9/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    677         except KeyError:
    678             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 679             raise KeyError(key) from None
    680         return self.decodevalue(value)
    681 

KeyError: 'COLAB_TPU_ADDR'
```

It is very frustrating because this is almost all the notebook give the same error. Except [this one](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/diffusers/stable_diffusion_fast_jax.ipynb), which gives the error

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1360d59fd674> in <module>
      7 
      8 get_ipython().system('pip install flax diffusers transformers ftfy')
----> 9 jax.devices()
     10 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jax/_src/xla_bridge.py in devices(backend)
    541     List of Device subclasses.
    542   """
--> 543   return get_backend(backend).devices()
    544 
    545 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jax/_src/xla_bridge.py in get_backend(platform)
    483 @lru_cache(maxsize=None)  # don't use util.memoize because there is no X64 dependence.
    484 def get_backend(platform=None):
--> 485   return _get_backend_uncached(platform)
    486 
    487 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jax/_src/xla_bridge.py in _get_backend_uncached(platform)
    473     if backend is None:
    474       if platform in _backends_errors:
--> 475         raise RuntimeError(f"Backend '{platform}' failed to initialize: "
    476                            f"{_backends_errors[platform]}")
    477       raise RuntimeError(f"Unknown backend {platform}")

RuntimeError: Backend 'tpu_driver' failed to initialize: Could not initialize backend 'tpu_driver'
```

I have double checked that TPU is actually available. What I suspect is this line:

```
jax.tools.colab_tpu.setup_tpu('tpu_driver_20221011')
```

I am still digging through jax API to see this function. At the moment, any recommendation is welcome.

FYI: Jax and Jaxlib version is of 0.4.6.

Answer (score 3):

JAX 0.4 and newer requires TPU VMs, which Colab does not provide at this time. You can still use jax 0.3.25 on Colab TPU, which is the version that comes installed by default on Colab TPU runtimes. If you've already updated JAX, you can choose *Runtime->Disconnect and Delete Runtime* to get a fresh TPU VM, and then skip the `pip install` step so that you keep the default jax/jaxlib version 0.3.25.

Remember JAX on Colab TPU needs a setup step to be run before any other JAX operation:

```py
import jax.tools.colab_tpu
jax.tools.colab_tpu.setup_tpu()
```

Comment: If you use 0.3.25 what I get is you have to use at least 0.4.4 for TPU.

Comment: Can you say more about what's leading to this message? I just tried on a fresh Colab TPU runtime, ran the TPU setup step [here](https://github.com/google/jax#pip-installation-colab-tpu), then executed a number of JAX examples without issue.

Comment: I will explain later on. I am having a fever at the moment.

Comment: HI. Check out this https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/flax/blob/main/examples/imagenet/imagenet.ipynb#scrollTo=4EzOChfJeVrU. This is in the flax official example.

Comment: That example is running `pip install flax`, which installs the latest version of `flax`, which requires newer `jax` versions than are supported by the Colab TPU. You'll need to use an older flax version; e.g. `pip install jax==0.3.25 jaxlib==0.3.25 flax==0.6.2`

Comment: Let me try immediately.

Comment: Also, if I use jax==0.4.4, jaxlib==0.4.4, what will be the corresponding flax edition?

Comment: You cannot use Jax 0.4 or newer on Colab TPU.

Comment: OK. I already have another problem. It says `ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
orbax 0.1.5 requires jax>=0.4.6, but you have jax 0.3.25 which is incompatible.` So which version of orbax I can use?

Comment: I don't know anything about orbax, but comparing  https://pypi.org/project/orbax/#history to https://pypi.org/project/jax/#history, it looks iike orbax 0.0.23 was released when jax 0.3.25 was the newest available, so I'd probably try that.

Comment: I see the problem is `!pip install ml-collections`. This contains a huge number of libraries, many of them unrelated to the `jax` eco-system, but it will install the newest version. I think the only way for me to carry forward is to try every version (such as `optax` etc.) based on the python release.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252686/discussion-between-ranwang-and-jakevdp).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help of @jakevdp, I manage to get a running example.

First, this is the official [flax example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/flax/blob/main/examples/imagenet/imagenet.ipynb). The problem is when one is running this example, it is very clear that the versions are too old. According to @jakevdp, one has to be satisfied with the old version. Here is [the version](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rwbfd/511d749fa8be5410e0151824dad398d5/image_net_copy.ipynb) that I find successful.

However, there is still a catch, which I am not clear about. In the file `models.py` there is a line that appears twice.

```
y = self.norm(scale_init=nn.initializers.zeros_init())(y)
```

This causes a mistake since `zeros_init` is not part of the flax version that I use. I have deleted all the initialization arguments. so these two lines become

```
y = self.norm()(y)
```

Perhaps, I should change it to `zeros()` which is in the version of flax I use. However, since I am more interested in running the pipeline till it works, I didn't do that.

As a final notice, I am not sure what this code will do on a TPU VM. I am still trying to understand the code as it is rather complex.